# Edit Approve/Reject votes don't reset at 0:00 UTC

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

I just noticed that I got all of my mod flags back, but I am still not able to vote to approve/reject edit suggestions.

How does a 'day' work according to edit Approve/Reject votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "day" actually refers to the last 24 hours, so it is a rolling day that starts 24 hours ago.

Clearly a bug ....

Just fixed it, will be deployed later today.

Comment: Shouldn't it be changed to coincide with the behavior of the rest of the site?

Comment: @George, yes probably makes sense